Wiring basics for timer relay
I'm not an engineer or electrician, but trying to figure out how I can make this timer relay work for my project. Or figure out if there's a different timer relay better suited to the job.
The relay is a Finder 80.01.0.240.0000. Datasheet is here - page 1 80.01
I'm using the interval function (DI).

I'm taking a 120v signal from a high level indicator and putting it on the A1 terminal. When A1 is energized I want to sound a horn for 2mins, then after 2mins I want the horn to turn off and on a separate circuit I want to then run a strobe light for as long as A1 stays energized. Once A1 is de-energized the timer relay would reset.
My thinking is if I jump A1 to 15 on this relay, then I can power the timed horn off of 18 and after that times out power the light off of 16.
The output contact on the level indicator is rated for plenty of amperage and can handle powering both the horn and the light. Is there any reason this is a bad idea to jump from A1 to 15?

Is it ok for the  strobe to be on while the horn is on or do you want it only come on after the horn turns off?

Your thinking is correct. Just power the strobe from the sensor. (I wasn't sure if that's what you were intending.)

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Yes, it's fine the way you described. The contacts and input are all rated for mains voltage so as long as the strobe and horn are 120VAC too it will be fine.
If you want the strobe to start when the horn stops, use the back contact (16) just as you suggest. If you want the strobe to operate the whole time, then just wire it across the input.
